# Pandas.read_csv reads all of the file into one column

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas, anaconda

I have a csv file in the form "...","...","..."... with over 40 columns.
When I used this simple code, it only gives me one massive key. I've been messing with it for over an hour and I can't figure how to use pandas to fix this.

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv(filePath, header=0, encoding='iso-8859-1')
datakeys = dataframe.keys();
print(datakeys)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the first few lines of the csv, also what are you intending with `header=0`, this just means that the first line is the header, are you intending `header=None` which means no header, is that your error?

Comment: I only put the header there to clearly indicate to others that the first line of the csv was the labels.
I can't post specific data because HIPPA sucks, but it follows the format i posted. With strings or numbers. In the labels whitespaces are designated by underscores and there are no numbers. Isn't panda supposed to.. you know.. separate values based on the commas on its own?

Comment: Can you configure the separation character? You assume it is ',' but some tools depend on system settings or can be configured and use ';' by default

Comment: @V15I0N I tried that with no luck based on the API. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: The default value for `sep` is `','` so it should've worked but really unless you post raw input data it's just a guessing game now

Comment: Are you sure you have ',' or just a glyphen looking like ','?

Comment: What does `dataframe.columns` give you? Certainly sample text of the first few rows of the csv would help here.

Comment: What is the 'quotechar'? The spec gives no default?

Comment: @V15I0N the quoting level is `QUOTE_MINIMAL` whatever that means, basically it'll sniff the dtype so strings and values don't need quotes in order for them to be treated as strings

Comment: @EdChum I can't post raw data but it  follows the form I said. Each entry is in quotes and separated with a comma with no space. Inside the quotes there is never another quote or comma either.

Comment: @vk1011 dataframe.columns is identical to dataframe.keys() (literally keys() returns self.columns)

Answer (score 7):

I fixed the issue by specifying `names` field of `read_csv` and `header=None`.

```
fields = ["colA", "colB"];
df = pd.read_csv("/tmp/data.csv", sep="|", header=None, names=fields)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since these answers did not satisfy me, but I found another way, I'm also posting my solution here:

So I was using "§" as separator and `pandas-1.1.5`. However, the problem was the same as described by the question maker (apart from the separator). My solution was to update pandas:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pandas
```

After that, with

```
    df = pd.read_csv(input_file_path, sep="§", encoding='utf8', quotechar='"', engine="python")
```

everything went fine.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by writing a script to reformat the .csv
There was a minor formatting issue in the .csv that was causing Panda to basically do nothing. Weird

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but as I recently encountered the same issue, thought I post what fixed it for me:

The problem was setting the `sep=` argument incorrectly. When put the appropriate separator (double check your data file for the correct separator!), it read the file into the correct number of columns.

Maybe it helps others as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably a bit late, but just specifying the separator seems to fix it