# Pandas read_csv does not separate values after comma

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to load some .csv data in the Jupyter notebook but for some reason, it does not separate my data but puts everything in a single column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = 
pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\leonm\Documents\Fontys\Semester 
4\GriefBot_PracticeChallenge\DummyDataGriefbot.csv')
df.head()
```

[My csv data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVH8l.png)
[image]

In this picture there is the data I am using.

And now I do not understand why my values all come in single column and are not separated where the comas are.
I have also tried both spe=',' and sep=';' but they do not change anything.

[This is what I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XkxW.png)
[image]
I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42383747/5568675). Good first question though, the code and output is always appreciated.

Comment: Post the first few lines of your CSV as text and not as an image. I'm guessing each list is quoted. Even your Excel reads it in as one column.

Comment: "list" should have been "line". I'm guessing each line is quoted.

Comment: I think you need to pass header parameter

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your CSV file data as text. Use a text editor to open it (not-Excel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's how your data looks in a CSV reader like Excel, then each row likely looks like one big string in a text editor.

```
"ID,PERSON,DATE"
"1,A. Molina,1593147221"
"2,A. Moran, 16456"
"3,Action Marquez,15436"
```

You could of course do "text to columns" within Excel and resave your file, or if you have many of these files, you can use the Pandas `split` function.

```py
df[df.columns[0].split(',')] = df.iloc[:,0].str.split(',', expand=True)
#  ^ split header by comma        ^         ^ create list split by comma, and expand
#                                 |           each list entry into a new column
#                                 | select first column of data                
df.head()
>    ID,PERSON,DATE         ID  PERSON          DATE
> 0  1,A. Molina,1593147221 1   A. Molina       1593147221
> 1  2,A. Moran, 16456      2   A. Moran        16456
> 2  3,Action Marquez,15436 3   Action Marquez  15436
```

You can then use `pd.drop` to drop that first column if you have no use for it

```py
df.drop(df.columns[0], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you very much I was able to clean my data with text to columns in excel. My data looked exactly like you showed, where every row has 2 semi-columns around it.